# Salt concentration versus depth due to diffusion and gravity

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, diffusion

Suppose we have a container of water with dissolved salt in it. Though it begins as a homogeneous mixture, gravity will have a tiny effect on the distribution of the ions. Another user found the result [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/173809/186128):

> The drift velocity of a particle of mass $m$ under gravity in a fluid
> of viscosity $\xi$ is $mg/\xi$, from which it follows that the
> relevant diffusion equation is
>
> $$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial
>  z^2}+\frac{mg}{\xi}\frac{\partial C}{\partial z} $$
>
> The steady-state ($\partial C/\partial t=0$) solution is of the form
>
> $$ C(z)=\alpha \frac{D\xi}{mg}e^{-mgz/\xi D}+\beta $$
>
> where $\alpha,\beta$ can be solved by imposing appropriate boundary
> conditions.

where if you plug in numbers for salt ions, you get basically no variation in a modestly sized container of water.

However, I'm wondering if this solution is ignoring the other effect of gravity, buoyancy. Once water at the bottom becomes slightly saltier, I'm thinking it should become more dense and then prefer to sink and not mix as well with the less-salty water above it.

I found an answer on the web [here](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/ask/listing/24631), which says that the expected salt concentration by depth would be (using $C$ and $z$ for the concentration and depth instead):

$$C(z) = C(0)\exp\left(-\frac{mgz}{2kT}\right)$$

I don't know if this answer is right. He says it is analogous to the ["law of atmospheres"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula), but $kT$ shows up there because of the ideal gas law: pressure is related to temperature. The case of salt concentration in water seems different, although the diffusion constant above depends on temperature. Is there some kind of buoyant effect like this for salt dissolved in water or not? Which of these, if either, is the right answer? The exponential factors are about 8 orders of magnitude apart between them.

Comment: Your two exponentials actually look as if the are at least proportional – see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory) (a kind of fluctuation-dissipation theorem relating the diffusion constant to the temperature). I wouldn't expect multiple orders of magnitude. Note: The viscosity in the first equation seems to be in uncommon units. As the drift velocity is $mg/6\pi\eta r$, so it seems $\xi = 6\pi\eta r$ (with $r$ the particle radius). Note that using a classical sphere to model your ions may have varying mileage and the radius  will be "effecive" in aquaeus solution.

Comment: (Actually, $\xi$ seems to be the inverse particle motility $\mu$). So TL;DR: The second equation will give you the correct result – without having to input the particle motilities.

Comment: Oh I think that's it! $\xi$ isn't actually just the viscosity of the fluid... The Stokes radius of sodium ions is around 200 pm according to another paper that measured it. That gives the correct agreement between the two.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/754862/195949

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/748494/146039 for a very general stratification derivation (approach #2) that can be applied to salty water. *k* appears not because of the ideal gas but because the chemical potential incorporating gravity must be uniform at equilibrium. The chemical potential definition contains an entropy term, and the entropy definition contains *k*.